# Function returning Observable but having issue from returning nested value

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a function which returns an observable.

```
test(id: int): Observable<Group>{
  this.http.get('test/').subscribe( (result:any) => {
     resultingVal = Group.fromJson(result.group);
  });
}
```

and as of now, it doesnt return one, but you can see that I want to return a particular property in a nested observable.

I want it to return *returningVal* but i was confused as to the standard way to return this nested value.  I was thinking to turn it into a promise and wait it out then go into the data, I cleaned it up, but I believe it is kinda hacky.

```
test(id: int): Observable<Group>{
  let resultingVal = null
  let promise = this.http.get('test/').toPromise().then( result => {
     resultingVal = Group.fromJson(result.group);
  });
  return from(Promise.all([promise]).then( _ => resultingVal));
}
```

Is this promise solution the way to do to it, or is there a more clean version similar to above?  I feel using promises in this fashion is a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your question the test method not return an observable , you just need to return the get observable this will solve the part where test return an observable , you can use a map rxjs operator to transform the result by applying a function , to use any rxjs operator you need to use pipe and pipe just an rxjs operators composer.

```
test(id: int): Observable<Group>{
  return this.http.get('test/').pipe(map((result:any) => 
     Group.fromJson(result.group))
  );
}
```

to get the value you need to subscribe to the test method

```
test(10).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Could you document this perchance? im not sure what pipe does in comparison to subscribe or toPromise. I am unsure also of what the map function does.  Im taking a guess here, but it looks like it it pipes the output into a map function, which presumably flattens it, such that its return is an observable?  is *map* the more updated version of *switchMap*?

Comment: @FallenreaperI have update my answer hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I think this might be.  I have a personal thing where i wait a little before sayinig it is the right answer in case there are better answers. :) It looks like it may do the trick

Comment: @malnarmawi I noticed that your answer isnt syntactically correct. I think you you need an extra open paren after map.